# How do we show a total ordering using the < symbol.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, order-theory

Let's say we have a relation R (which is a partial ordering) where x R y means that x comes before or precedes y in the ordering.

We have the following information about R

(a R c)|(c R g)| (g R d)| (d R f) | (g R e) | (e R h) | (h R f) | (b R h) | (i R b) | (i R e)

How do we show total ordering < that is compatible with what we know about the partial ordering above?

Do we just show that each letter is < the other?

Comment: do you want to construct a total order which respects the existing relation and only adds some additional relations to make it a total order? or what are you asking?

Comment: I want to show that it is a total order based on the given info

Answer (score 0):

One obvious thing you can do is to find an actual order the elements compatible with the given information. Here is one:

$$a<c<g<d<i<b<e<h<f$$

Comment: Would that be a way to prove that it's a total ordering?

Comment: @user3238863 By saying that the $<$ is transitive, yes.